# Split list by string names

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

I would like to split a list of strings into groups matching part of the name. This is so I can group items by their parent folder and any children of this folder collect all files from.

For example:

```
# Search for and append all files to list in the directory + subdirectories.
def getFilePaths(directory):
    file_paths = []    
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths

# Assign all found files to variable 'all_files'.
all_files = getFilePaths(INPUT_DIRECTORY)

#OUTPUT IS:
/Accessories\ornate clock\clock.jpg
/Accessories\ornate clock\3d\clock.max
/Library_Test/Eames Chair\chair.max
/Library_Test/Eames Chair\maps\timber.jpg
```

I now want to create a new list from this and anything that matches the parent folder 'ornate clock' or 'eames chair' is put into this list. However this will be thousands of folders with different names so it needs to match automatically the parent name or what I was thinking is any file found that has the same folder structure (ornate clock) puts all the files together that matches that name.

Example of Current directory layout:

```
Library (root directory)
-Accessories
--Ornate Clock
---Clock.3ds
---Maps
----Map1.jpg
----Map2.jpg

-Dining Chairs
--Dining Chair1
---DiningChair1.3ds
---Maps
----DiningChair.jpg

--DiningChair2
---3D
----DiningChair2.3ds
----DiningChair2.jpg
```

I have tried using glob, os.walk, regex, list operations. All examples I find online require the user to supply something to match to such as all_files.split('ornate clock') but this name will constantly change.

For Example this is how I want the end result to look like:

```
Library (root directory)
-Accessories
--Ornate Clock
---Clock.3ds
---Map1.jpg
---Map2.jpg

-Dining Chairs
--Dining Chair1
---DiningChair1.3ds
---DiningChair.jpg

--DiningChair2
---DiningChair2.3ds
---DiningChair2.jpg
```

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual issue you are trying to solve by grouping files by some of their parent directory? What is your end goal?

Comment: The issue im trying to solve is: I want to restructure a library of files, but the order is a mess. So some folders have multiple directories of files I need to all be placed in one folder - the parent folder. But I need to determine what is the parent folder. This is done by saying if there is no files in this directory - only folders this is not a parent. If a parent has atleast 1 file, and then multiple directories below it with more files this is the parent folder, and all files below this should be moved up to the parent.

Comment: It can look a lot like this: Library/Chairs/Dining/Chair1, this is the parent because below this may be other folders with files such as Preview, Textures, 3D Files. But the next folder in the library will be: Library/Chairs/Dining/Chair2. But Chair2 may have all its files already in the parent folder and no children folders. Each directory has a different structure so I need to determine something similar - which would be the name Chair2 or Chair1 and say ok anything below this is to be grouped together under Chair1 (the parent for this directory of files)

Comment: put this explanation in question - it will be more readable. And create example with expected result.

Comment: Why isn't Dining Chairs in your expected output?

Comment: vekerdyb youre right, ill update it to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should preferably use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which is built-in in Python.

```
parents = {}
for path in Path("the source directory").glob("*.*"):
    if str(path.parent) not in parents: 
       parents[str(path.parent)] = [path.name]
    else: 
       parents[str(path.parent)].append(path.name)
```

**EDIT:** You can also use `path.parents` which will return a list of all the parents i.e. `../../../` except their names. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents

`path.parents` will return you a list of parents path names in descending order i.e. starting with the depth and then up wards `../../../`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for replying. My main issue here is actually splitting this list into more lists based on the parent name of the folder. But the parent name will always be different, how to I create a list for each parent so that all its children files will be grouped together?

Comment: Hi John, Im not sure If I follow here. After doing this I type print(parents) and I see an empty set?

Comment: @JamesVella, did you import `pathlib`, `from pathlib import Path` and then `Path("...")` replace **...** with the directory path.

Comment: @JamesVella, did you provide the directory path. 
`_path = Path(r"c:\windows\system32")
paths = _path.parents` in your case it is your path.

Comment: yes I have. Im not having trouble with the original list, Im happy with the list I have. I am having trouble with splitting this current list into catagorized lists based on the parent folder that has files within this - regardless of how many subdirectories that parent has. I have updated my original question if that helps at all.

Comment: @JamesVella, try: `rglob` instead.